# SSAS installation on Linux machine (CentOS 7)

Tags: sql, linux, ssas, onpremises-gateway

I have a Virtual Machine with Linux (CentOS 7) with SQL server installed in it. Can I install SSAS in the machine and connect it through my local machine through SSMS? If so, how can I do so? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis Services is not available for SQL Server 2019 on Linux

[Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Unsupported features and services.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-ver15#Unsupported)